# Angular2 RC5 shared Component between Modules

Tags: angular

I'm just updating my `angular2-app` to new `RC5`. I got quite far, and everything seems ok, but now I want to re-organize it into `NgModules` and came across one thing: 
I used a component ("ComponentA") across multiple other components in different Modules (say ModuleA & ModuleB).

As soon as use it that way, I get an:

> Uncaught Type ComponentA is part of the
>   declarations of 2 modules: ModuleA and ModuleB!

Error.

As far as I see, the only way to get around that is to use a `Shared-Module` with all my common stuff, is that right? Or is there an easier way to share components across Modules?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/@alihaghighatkhah/creating-a-shared-module-in-angular2-d281632316ff#.w0dpsvf48) article might help you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to make a module for the shared component and import this module where you want to use this component.

As the error messages says a component (or directive, or pipe) can only be listed in `directives` of exactly one module.

If you want to reuse, then you need to add the module that contains it to `@NgModule({imports: [...]})` of the module where you want to use it.

Comment: I was afraid that was the only answer.. ;)   Thank you for your lightning-fast response [ Will accept as soon as so let's me ]

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer's link has a great walkthrough on how to get this setup. Also explains how to have a core (or services) module to avoid having to name the services as providers in each module. Just navigate to shared module: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module

Answer (score 3):

I make a module that contains ALL my shared components.

This makes it much easier to import it in my other modules.

Pro tip: put routing into your modules, and try - just for fun -  to make one of them lazy loaded.

Then you'll think: "whoaaaaa modules are cooooolllll"

Comment: Hehe, thank's for your reply. After adding a shared module I realized it's pros... It's a good thing after all, yes! Lazy loading is on my to do list up next.

Comment: If it helps, I have made a repo on Github which makes a demo app using Angular2, Webpack2, Typescript2 and Angular-Material. I the app I bump together all the material-components into a shared ngModule which I then use. You can run the repo inside a Docker container as well. https://github.com/spock123/angular2-webpack2-typescript2

Comment: I'm following this approach; my shared module contains e.g. my header and footer components. But as the shared module doesn't have routing, I can't have routerlinks in my header. How do you fix that? Have a separate header component for each module?

Comment: Just import the RouterModule  in your shared module.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use shared module.

SharedModule exists to make commonly used components, directives and pipes available for use in the templates of components in many other modules.

You have to export & import it in other modules where ever you want.

for more details see the link [shared module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module)